# WPF DataGrid switch template between view mode and edit mode

Tags: wpf, datagrid, templating

If have a WPF `DataGrid` on the left of a Window with an area to the right for displaying the selected record. The selected record consists of `Textbox`es and `ComboBox`es that are disabled until the edit button is clicked. All works as expected.

However, it seems a bit clumsy to be populating `ComboBox`es when the `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid` being changed. A much lighter control such as a `TextBlock` could be used until the Edit button is clicked, then the `TextBlock`s could be switched out for `ComboBox`es.

I'm sure this can be done with some sort of templating but when I tried to experiment with this, all of the events that are associated with the `ComboBox`es report an error as they're no longer present as they have been replace with TextBlocks in "View mode".

I'm probably going about this wrong so some guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is excelent [article](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing)

To apply single-click editing to all cells in the DataGrid

1. Paste the style below into the Resources of your DataGrid
2. Paste the method into the code behind

To apply single-click editing to only certain cells in the DataGrid

1. Set an x:Key on the Style (ex. )
2. Paste the style into the Resources of your DataGrid
3. Apply the style to the CellStyle property of the columns which you'd like to have single click editing (ex. )
4. Paste the method into the code behind

   ```
   //
   // SINGLE CLICK EDITING
   //
   private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
       if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
       {
           if (!cell.IsFocused)
           {
               cell.Focus();
           }
           DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
           if (dataGrid != null)
           {
               if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
               {
                   if (!cell.IsSelected)
                       cell.IsSelected = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
                   if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
                   {
                       row.IsSelected = true;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }    

   static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
   {
       UIElement parent = element;
       while (parent != null)
       {
           T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
           if (correctlyTyped != null)
           {
               return correctlyTyped;
           }

           parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Arsenmkrt, I've seen some of Dr WPF's articles but you're right, this one is along the lines of what I'm looking for.

Comment: This link has died try here instead: http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing

Answer (score 1):

The ContentTemplateSelector property should allow you to select one template or another depending on the current mode (view/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer link is dead.

This may help instead:
http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing